# Set Custom Keyboard as default

Tags: javascript, java, android

Hey I created a custom keyboard for android studio following a tutorial.
But to use it I have to change the Keyboard on the device on my own. Is there any method to avoid this, so that my custom keyboard shows up automatically when I open the app.

Comment: If the question is how to open the custom keyboard only in your app, and as soon as it opens, I would just make a KeyboardView layout and display it in your application.

Comment: Thank you for the information.